# Load a pdf with a chinese filename from url

Tags: javascript, url, httprequest, tomcat6

I have a local pdf and I try load this pdf in an iframe by the path of the file.

The file has a name 明星.pdf and the path is like this:
[http://localhost:8080/path-here/明星.pdf](http://localhost:8080/path-here/%E6%98%8E%E6%98%9F.pdf)

When I try open the pdf file, the browser do this request and fails (404):
http://localhost:8080/path-here/%E6%98%8E%E6%98%9F.pdf

The problem only occurs with pdfs that contains chinese characteres.

Any suggestion?

PS: I'm using javascript.

Edit:

Example:

```
//there's a http:// in front, I can't put more links in post
var url = 'localhost:8080/path-here/teste.pdf' 
var url2 = 'localhost:8080/path-here/明星.pdf'

window.open(url,"_blank") //works fine
window.open(url2,"_blank") //fails
```

Comment: I see `javascript` in your question tags. Would you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can handle most non-english characters, but you'll probably need to encode them for the web browser to recognise them. Try specifying the webpage (server?)'s charset as UTF-8

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
```

You'll likely also need to prepare your string for the webbrowser, I suggest using *encodeURIcomponent()* or *encodeURI()*. Here's an explanation of the function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent. Hope that helps!

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html RFC 1738 says not to use non ascii characters in urls, which is in part why you're having this problem (uncommon use case). What server / setup are you using with it? Make sure to set your URIEncoding to UTF-8 on that too

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987 RFC3987 introduces IRIs, which allow unencoded UTF-8 if you want a more permanent fix. Not sure whether they're usable in javascript though, you'd have to do some research.

Comment: It's a tomcat server, uri enconding is set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this, use

```
<a href="yourfilepath" download="your_chinesefilename.pdf",
```

**EXAMPLE :**

```
<a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>
<button onclick="downloadWagePdf()">
    pdfdownloadceshi 
</button>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function downloadWagePdf() {
        var pdfFilePath = "<%=basePath%>" + "WebRoot\\download\\" + "bank_wage" + ".xls";
        var titleDate= new Date().Format("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
        document.getElementById("dlink").href = pdfFilePath;
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = "银行流水表"+titleDate+".xls";
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();
    }

</script>
```

you can look [this url](http://blog.csdn.net/leytton/article/details/38545299), how to use  download