# Open file with JavaScript containing non ASCII characters (German)

Tags: javascript, url

I have a MS Word path of a file on my network that I want to open using JavaScript. The problem is that this works fine if the file path contains ASCII characters but doesn't work if it contain letters like ü,ö,ä

```
let path1= 'file://MyFolder/testatur.docx';
let path2= 'file://MyFolder/testätür.docx';

  window.open('ms-word:ofe|u|' + path1); //this works
  window.open('ms-word:ofe|u|' + path2); //this doesn't work
```

Could anyone guide me about what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this issue?

Comment: What have you done to research the problem? Seems like a text encoding issue.

Comment: Being Windows, it probably expects the path in CP-1252 encoding or something like that.

Comment: I have tried to encode the url before passing it to window.open() but it still didn't work

Comment: I have also read other solutions but none of them work for me e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862190/load-a-pdf-with-a-chinese-filename-from-url